# How can i get the max-value out of a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

so in MySQL I have the task to filter out those customer names with the max overall revenue. I used the following query:

```
SELECT name
FROM
   (SELECT name, SUM(sale_price) as revenue
   FROM customer
   INNER JOIN order USING(customerID)
   INNER JOIN orderdetails USING(ordernumber)
   GROUP BY name) as revenues
   WHERE revenues.revenue = (SELECT MAX(revenue)
                        FROM revenues);
```

Now I understand, I cannot reference the alias of the subquery in my WHERE-clause. But how can I filter out only those names with the max value without more or less writing the same query as a filter again?

Thank you!

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Hey, I'm using version 8.0.20

Comment: You do have to write the same query again to get the max.leave it to the optimizer to work out whether it needs to be executed more than once..

Comment: Your query does not "filter out" the maximum customers.  "Filtering out" would mean that the result set does not have them.  You might want to fix the language if your intention is to get the highest revenue customers.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using version 8.0.20

```
WITH 
revenues AS (SELECT name, 
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sale_price) DESC) dr
             FROM customer
             INNER JOIN order USING (customerID)
             INNER JOIN orderdetails USING (ordernumber)
             GROUP BY name),
SELECT name
FROM revenues
WHERE dr = 1
```